# Firebase Javascript web .on returns null on first request

Tags: javascript, firebase

Recently I started learning how to read and write in firebase for a web-page, but in my log-in form, when I pressed submit, it would say that the entry was incorrect, yet when I press submit again, it would work and say that I was logged in.

I logged (console.log) what was being read and realized that on the first click, it returned null, but when I pressed again, it would return the correct data. I tried using "async" and "await", but the problem was still there.

Here is my Javascript code:

```js
async function read(dbRef){
 let ret = null;
 dbRef.on('value', function(snapshot){
  ret = snapshot.val();
 }, function(error){
  alert('The read failed: ' + error.code);
 });
 let result = await ret;
 return result;
}
async function logIn(){
 let uName = document.getElementById('liName').value;
 let password = document.getElementById('liPass').value;
 let realPass = await read(db.ref('users/' + uName + '/password/'));
 if (realPass == password){
  alert('Logged in as ' + uName);
 } else if (realPass == null) {
  alert('Incorrect username or password');
 }
}
```

This question has been answered before concerning IOS and Android, but I couldn't use the code or answers because I was using javascript. If you could answer in JS terms, that would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`on()` is asynchronous.  It returns *immediately*, before any data is available.  Then, after some time, when the data becomes available, your callback function is invoked with the snapshot.

Your code is assuming that `on()` returns data immediately and calls your callback immediately.  This is not the case.  You need to assume that data is only available *after* the callback in invoked.

In other words, you can't make an asynchronous function like `on()` to be synchronous and return a value to a function caller.  This is a common mistake.

Also, if you only need to query for data a single time and not listen for updates over time, you should use `once()` instead of `on()`.